# Добавление и удаление класса по ширине div

Tags: javascript, jquery

В JS я новичок.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.
Смысл такой, при ширине размера блока равной 775px должен удаляться класс .col-460 а вместо него добавляться другой класс .col-620, ну и соответственно наоборот.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.content').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this), width = $this.width();
            if (width < 775) {
                $this.removeClass('col-620');
                $this.addClass('col-460');
            } else if (width > 775) {
                $this.removeClass('col-460');
                $this.addClass('col-620');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Kirill  Seleznev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

```
if($('div').width() >= 666 ) {
    $('div').removeClass('666').addClass('999');
}
```

Нo! У меня такое чувство, что вам это нужно для адаптивной верстки. Если да, то используйте css-правило `@media`, тип `queries`. Пример на хабре [Адаптивный и мобильный дизайн с CSS3 Media Queries](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/)